# tfidf w2v giving NaN values

Tags: python, word2vec, tf-idf

While using TFIDF Word2Vec giving `NaN` values on the review of Amazon fine foods dataset after sampling it to 100k data points I am getting `NaN` values in the sentence vector...
I tried almost everything with the code but am not getting real values..

After printing the sentence array this is the output I am getting -

```
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan].....
```

The code is as follows -

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), analyzer='word')
final_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(final_data['CleanedText'].values)
tfidf_feat = tfidf.get_feature_names()
tf_sent_vectors = []
row = 0

for sent in list_of_sent:
    sent_vec = np.zeros(50)  #initializiing the sent_vec
    weighted_sum = 0   #initializing the weightedsum
    for word in sent:
        try:
            vec = w2v_modelk.wv[word]
            tf_idf = final_tfidf[row, tfidf_feat.index(word)]   
            sent_vec += (vec * tf_idf)
            weighted_sum += tf_idf
        except:
            pass
    sent_vec /= weighted_sum
    print(sent_vec)
    row += 1
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated !!

Comment: what is the name of your "sentence array" variable?

Comment: The name of the sentence vector is sent_vec

Comment: is your code working fine before 100k data points?

Comment: I didnt try it as 100k data points was handled by my system without any memory error. Trying it on original data set(500k) was giving me a memory error

Comment: it would be helpful if you give us `final_data['CleanedText'].head()`

Comment: Check that `vec = w2v_modelk.wv[word]` really output words because your except does nothing and pass to `sent_vec /= weighted_sum` where you divide np.zero(50) by 0

Answer (score -2):

Here According to your code  tf-idf features may be like {'hi','jik','this by' etc} .

Because of uni grams and bi grams.so till here it ok

But the critical section is

"for word in sentence:"

For suppose if the sentence=["This is good"]

so tf-idf feaures be {'This','is','good','This is','is good'}

Now line in code

for word in sentence:

we get output as{'T','h','i','s', and so no } we get single characters

so as these single characters might not be in tf-idf and might not be in w2vec model

i.e The correction would be     for word in sentence.split(" "):